# Any open source project for "Application Virtualization Engine" on Android?

Tags: android, open-source, virtualization

I want to develop an APP that can run multiple accounts on Android(like LBE), so I'm looking for an open source project for Application Virtualization Engine on Android which is a high technical threshold for me and there's no way to implement it myself.

Through Google search, I found two related projects, but neither of them is open source (one of them was open source before)

VirtualApp: https://github.com/asLody/VirtualApp/blob/master/README_eng.md

SpaceCore: https://spacecore.dev

The above projects are for enterprise customers, so the price is very high and unaffordable for me.

I'm looking for open source projects of this type, if anyone knows of any, please share them, thanks a lot!

Comment: Recommendation requests are off-topic for stack overflow, but this may be on topic for [softwarerecs.se].  Before posting there, check out their [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336).

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the reminder. I am a newbee here, it was my fault for not reading the question quality guidelines carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier in this year, I did the same search for such kind of projects due to my company's business needs. An open source project was my highest priority, but same as you, I didn't find one, but found several commercial products and most of them came from China, I don't know why that is.

"VirtualApp" was originally an open source project, but the founder Lody "illegally" removed the GPL and turned it into a commercial product in China. The source code on Github is an older version and is no longer updated.

"360DroidPlugin" is a product from a Chinese software security company in September this year.

"SpaceCore" is a product from a small team called S.O.T, which is the service provider our company finally chose. The reason is that its price is much lower than other service providers, and its performance and compatibility are not bad.

I don't think you can find an open source project of it, because if a project has commercial value, there is no good reason to open source it.